# Issues with Comparing DateTime

Tags: python, datetime

I am currently trying to compare an array of times with current time and execute certain code.

```
import os
import datetime as dt

t1 = dt.time(hour=12, minute=45)
t2 = dt.time(hour=12, minute=47)
timetable = [t1, t2]

for i in timetable:
    if i[0,1] == dt.datetime.now().hour and i[2,4] == dt.datetime.now().minute:
        print("Its working...")

    else:
        print ("time is now changed")
```

Currently giving the format like above for specific times.
I tried entering time as string like `timetable = ["12:45", "12:50"]` or integer as `timetable = [(12),(45),(12),(50)]`

but all methods give me different errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
if i[0,1] == dt.datetime.now().hour and i[2,4] == dt.datetime.now().minute:
```

to

```
if i.hour == dt.datetime.now().hour and i.minute == dt.datetime.now().minute:
```

timetable contains two datetime objects, not four separate strings of h, m, h, m.

For example, the first i would be datetime(hour=12, minute=45), so extract hour from it with *i.hour*.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```py
import datetime as dt

t1 = dt.time(hour=12, minute=45)
t2 = dt.time(hour=12, minute=47)
timetable = [t1, t2]
```

In your array `timetable`, your now have two times.

When you iterate over this array, in your `i` you have one time, and then the other. In python, you can actually directly compare times together:

```py
for i in timetable:
    # i is a datetime here, you can't access its content with i[0, 1] or anything
    # to copare it with the time now, you can do this instead:
    if i > dt.datetime.now().time():
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will be very useful in other function i am executing.

Answer (score 1):

```py
timetable = ["12:45", "12:50"]

for i in timetable:
    hour, minute = i.split(':')
    if int(hour) == dt.datetime.now().hour and int(minute) == dt.datetime.now().minute:
        print("Its working...")

    else:
        print ("time is now changed")
```